# Bar graph showing the structure of the game collection depending on genre and accessibility

Tags: r, ggplot2

Correlation diagram is working and looks good, but Bar graph didn't. Please help to find mistake
The goal is to create the diagram shown below

```
library(viridis)
library(tidyr)

tabulka = table(Pocitacove_hry$Zanr_hry, Pocitacove_hry$Pristupnost)

tabulka_rad = round(prop.table(tabulka,1)*100, digits = 0)

for (i in 1:nrow(tabulka_rad)){             
  tabulka_rad[i,ncol(tabulka_rad)]= 100 - sum(tabulka_rad[i,1:(ncol(tabulka_rad)-1)]) 
}
tabulka_rad = t(tabulka_rad)


tabulka_rad_data = as.data.frame(tabulka_rad)
colnames(tabulka_rad_data) = c("Zanr", "Pristupnost", "Cetnosti")

write.csv2(tabulka_rad,"tabulka_rad.csv")


addmargins(round(prop.table(tabulka)*100, digits=0))
addmargins(tabulka_rad,2)

write.csv2(tabulka,"tabulka_DU3.csv")
write.csv2(tabulka_rad_data, "tabulka_rad_data.csv")


ggplot(Pocitacove_hry, aes(x = HodnKritici_out, y = ProdejSvet_out)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 13) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "cyan") +
  labs(x = "Hodnocení od kritiků (%)", y = "Počet prodaných kopií ve světě - miliony") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 11),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.5), "cm")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous()

tabulka_rad_data %>%
  mutate(Cetnosti = as.numeric(Cetnosti)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Pristupnost), y = Cetnosti, fill = Zanr)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Cetnosti, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = "black") +
  labs(
    x = "Přístupnost",
    y = "Kumulativní relativní četnost (%)",
    fill = "Žánr"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
    legend.position = "top"
  )
```

That's how it looks

[image]

Here's what i expecting to see

[image]

#### Data:

```
dput(tabulka_rad_data)

structure(list(Zanr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L), levels = c("37", "45", "51", "54", "55", "60", "62", 
"63", "65", "66", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
"76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", 
"87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "93", "94", "96"), class = "factor"), 
    Pristupnost = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("Akční", "RPG", "Simulátor", 
    "Sportovní/Závodní", "Strategie", "Střílečka"), class = "factor"), 
    Cetnosti = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 
    0, 17, 4, 4, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 17, 8, 8, 0, 0, 
    8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 10, 
    20, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    17, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 8, 0, 0, 17, 0, 17, 8, 8, 0, 8, 0, 
    1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 9, 6, 6, 0, 3, 0, 3, -5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-222L))
```

Comment: Weclome to SO! According to the image of your chart `Zanr` is a factor or character with 30 different values. Hence, you have to recode this variable to get your desired result. But it's up to you to decide how you want to recode this variable. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()`.